# Python mock a dependancy object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a python class (MyClass) I am unit testing. It has a external dependency which creates a database, I would like to mock that object and check it was called.

```
from entities_database import DBCreator

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DBCreator()

    def create(self, name):
        value = self.db.create_db(name)
```

I would like to test the init function, so see that a mock DBCreator called. And then to test the create function to check that create_db() was called with "name", and it returned "name" to value.

I am not sure how to go about this, so far I have this:

```
from entities_database import DBCreator
from test_unit import MyClass
import unittest
import mock


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('entities_database.DBCreator', autospec=True)
    def test_myclass_init(self, dbcreator_mock):
        creator = mock.create_autospec(DBCreator)
        dbcreator_mock.return_value = creator

        myclass = MyClass()
        assert(dbcreator_mock.called)
```

Which results in:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_myclass_init (unit_test.MyClassTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paul/Data/TSC/Code/parltrack_eu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/paul/Data/TSC/Code/parltrack_eu/unit_test.py", line 32, in test_myclass_init
    assert(dbcreator_mock.called)
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.036s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

How can I fix my code?

---- UPDATE ----
Apart from the solution below with dependency injection, one can also do the following with patch, as suggested below @Goyo

```
from entities_database import DBCreator
from test_unit import MyClass
import unittest
import mock


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('test_unit.DBCreator', autospec=True)
    def test_myclass_init(self, mock_db):
        '''
        Test the initialization of MyClass
        Test that DBCreator is initialized
        '''
        creator = mock.create_autospec(DBCreator)
        mock_db.return_value = creator

        # Assert that the DBCreator is initialised
        myclass = MyClass()
        assert(mock_db.called)

    @mock.patch('test_unit.DBCreator', autospec=True)
    def test_myclass_create(self, mock_db):
        '''
        Test the myclass.create() function
        and assert it calls db.create_db() with the correct
        argument
        '''
        name = 'unittest'
        myclass = MyClass()
        myclass.create(name)
        # Assert that create_db was called with name
        myclass.db.create_db.assert_called_with(name)
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not enough of a problem description. Please give more details or even better post a [mcve]. Also I encourage you to use dependency injection instead of instantiating the dependency in the constuctor, that will make your class easier to test.

Comment: @Goyo, hope the edit addresses your concerns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patching is tricky. You have to patch the object in the same namespace where the SUT will look it up. In this case probably you want `@mock.patch('test_unit.DBCreator', autospec=True)`.

Using dependency injection avoids this kind of problems and makes things more explicit and clear:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def create(self, name):
        value = self.db.create_db(name)
```

Then in your test:

```
class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myclass_init(self):
        db = mock.Mock()
        myclass = MyClass(db)
        self.assertEqual(myclass.db, db)

    def test_myclass_create(self):
        db = mock.Mock()
        myclass = MyClass(db)
        name = mock.Mock()
        myclass.create(name)
        myclass.db.create_db.assert_called_once_with(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to try with your example code. But you should try to mock `create_db` function not `DBCreator` class.